# SQL: Get the first value

Tags: sql, greatest-n-per-group, hana

I have two tables:

patients(ID, Firstname, Lastname, ...)

records(ID, Date, Time, Version)

I want to (inner) join these tables, so I have the records with patient data, but in the column for Version I want always the first value that was recorded for the patient (so with the minimum of date and time dependent on the patient (id)). I tried with subquery but HANA doesn't allow ORDER-BY or LIMIT clause in subqueries.

How can I implement this with SQL? (HANA SQL)

Kind regards and thanks in advance.

Comment: Can you tell us a few things, such as how to join `patients` and `records`, or whether you have tried a query already?

Comment: I think HANA supports TOP instead of LIMIT

Comment: I think it's both possible @sagi. But both of them aren't supported in subqueries.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

HANA supports window functions, so you can join against a derived table that picks the first version:

```
select p.*, r.id, r.date, r.time, r.version
from patients p 
  join (
      select id, date, time, version, patient_id, 
             row_number() over (partition by patient_id order by version) as rn
      from records
  ) r on p.id = r.patient_id and r.rn = 1
```

The above assumes that the `records` table has a column `patient_id` that contains the id of the patients table to which that record belongs to.

Comment: I have tried and I think it works, if you add date and time in the order by clause. Thank you.

Comment: @ScientiaEtVeritas: it wasn't clear from your question how "first value" is defined.